# Div with image slider not inheriting height in Safari only

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am using Flickity slider for a single page web store. I have set the height to be 100% of the parent div on desktop screens. This works well on Chrome however does not work on Safari only.

HTML:

```
<div class="product__container">
        <div class="product__image--container">
            <div class="main-carousel">
                <div class="carousel-cell img--two"></div>
                <div class="carousel-cell img--one"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="product__description--container">
            
            <div class="product__description--aligner">
            
                <h1 class="product__title" style="margin-bottom: 0px; margin-top: 0px;"><strong>MYSTERY BOX</strong></h1>
                <p class="product__price">$25</p>
                <p><strong>The stuff:</strong> we spend our days working with cool brands with even cooler products.</p>
            
                <div id='product-component-83d33f1cc51'></div>
            
            </div>

</div>
```

Comment: You mention it works on Chrome, but not Safari. Have you tested it on other browsers?

Comment: And, the next/previous buttons are completely hidden in slide 5. That's not intentional I suppose

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sounds like a browser compatibility error. Especially if the element isn't working at all. (Your question is unclear as to if it doesn't work at all or it is displayed weird.) Try a browser compatibility checker. I like browsershots.com, but there are many other free tools that can check.

Comment: It does work, just the height of the image slider is not correct on safari only.

Comment: still could be a compatibility error did you check??

Comment: Haven't been able to find a good tool to check online. Any tips?

Comment: Did you try browsershots.com ??